# sealing conflic with oracle ojdbc

Tags: oracle, driver, ojdbc

After many search, i still got the following issue :

```
sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc is sealed
```

In my classpath there is one, and only one ojdbc.jar

I tried ojdbc14, ojdbc16, ojdbc5 and ojdbc6. I use maven+nexus. I don't know where the problem may come from.

Hint :

if i add the pom declaration of ojdbc then i remove it, it's working (no sealing execption),

if i add the pom declaration of ojdbc then i remove it AND do an eclipse:eclipse , it's not working anymore (no more OracleDriver in my project = no compil, kinda normal)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, there were only one ojdbc.jar in my classpath BUT there were a ojdbc dependency for a maven plugin.

Problem solved :)